# Not able to call servlet from jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm new in jsp servlet and unable to call servlet from jsp following is the code please let me know what is going wrong.
jsp code:

```
<form action="/myservlet" method="POST">
                    <div id="dialog" title="Enter the val">
    <input type="text" style="margin-left:10px"  valign="right" maxlength=4 size=4 name="myval" title="val"/>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
                        </div>      
                     </form>
```

servlet code:

```
 public class GetServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException 
        {
            System.out.println("******************* GetUserServlet  ******************");
            String name = request.getParameter("myval");
            boolean submitButtonPressed = request.getParameter("submit") != null;
            System.out.println("name: "+name+" submitButtonPressed:  "+submitButtonPressed);
        }}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>GetServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.GetServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: there is no error. Nothing happens after the submit button click.

Comment: What url you are hitting ?

Answer (score 0):

Your package name for the servlet class is invalid. You can not name the package as `package`. It is a reserved keyword for Java.

Read this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) to understand how package naming convention works.

If your servlet class `GetServlet` is in a package called `food.bar`, change the `<servlet-class>` tag in your `web.xml` from `package.GetServlet` to `food.bar.GetServlet`.

**Edit**

After you have edited your question, package name is not the issue. Remove the backslash from the form action string.

Keep `form action="myservlet"`

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience.  Actually the package name is not package I have just kept it as package for reading.

Comment: @Ameet, please show the actual code. If possible, show the bare minimum code with which you are able to reproduce the error.